# How to switch writing direction (LTR/RTL) in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, right-to-left

I received a word document that was probably created on a machine with some sort of right-to-left locale (e.g. Middle East). All text is in English but editing it is a pain. However, I can't figure out how I can switch the direction to left-to-right in Word 2007. The directions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/right-to-left-language-features-HA010351021.aspx#BM5) are not helping since I can't find the "Views" button or tab that I am supposed to click as described under "Set right-to-left text writing". So how do I switch? Thanks!

Comment: how is this question related to software development?

Comment: It's related to software documentation

Comment: If a question only has a programming answer, does that make it a programming question?

Comment: Off topic - xkcd [feels your pain](http://xkcd.com/1137/).

Comment: In the general sense you might want to read this article about [typing and using RTL text](http://dotancohen.com/howto/rtl_right_to_left.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Add and enable the alternate language under `Start / Programs / Microsoft Office / Microsoft Office Tools / 2007 Microsoft Office system Language Settings`
2. Click the round Office button:

   [image: 1]
3. Click **Word Options**:

   [image: 2]
4. Click **Customize**:

   [image: 3]
5. In the **Choose commands from** drop-down menu, select **Home Tab** instead of **Popular Commands**
6. Find and highlight **Left-to-Right Direction**, then click the **Add** button to move it to the **Customize Quick Access Toolbar** section
7. Add the **Right-to-Left Direction** command to the **QAT** as well
8. Now in the QAT you will see the **RTL** ([image: 4]) and **LTR** ([image: 5]) buttons, which you can use as required

Comment: I don't see the option. This is ms word 2010 but probably similar. What is one supposed to do from here? http://i.imgur.com/JfUReYY.png     and there's no home tab in the dropdown http://i.imgur.com/ir0r9IF.png

Comment: now I see it. under "all commands" though it's greyed out.

Answer (score 7):

Word left-to-right/right-to-left handling (LTR/RTL) works on two levels: the **paragraph** level, which can be controlled by right-clicking on the paragraph and choosing the appropriate direction (right-to-left, or left-to-right); and the **run** level.

Consider the following sequence of letters:

```
ABCD
```

This is an example of an LTR **run**. If we are using an RTL language, even though the sequence of letters is the same order, the text should be displayed in reverse, as a RTL run.

```
Actual order: ABCD
Visual order: DCBA
```

When we add netural characters -- characters that don't have rules about whether they are displayed as LTR or RTL -- the run direction cannot be determined based on the characters themselves; we have to explicitly define the direction of the run:

```
(assumes LTR paragraph direction)
Actual order:    ABCD0123
LTR run:         ABCD0123
partial RTL run: DCBA0123
full RTL run:    3210DCBA
```

When typing, there is no need for you to set the run direction; Word sets the run direction of a given neutral character based on the direction of the current language you are typing in.

In older versions of Word (<=2003), I didn't find any way to do this through the UI, only through the VBA editor.

1. Select the text you want to change
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA programming environment
3. Click on the **Immediate** pane; or if it's not visible, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
4. Type `Selection.LtrRun` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Note: To set the run to RTL, type `Selection.RtlRun`

In Word 2010, you can customize the ribbon by adding the commands `LtrRun` and `RtlRun` to set the LTR/RTL run direction.

Comment: I pressed ALT+F11 but I am not seeing "Immediate" anywhere. Can you help me locate it?

Comment: If you don't see the Immediate pane, press CTRL+G

Comment: Tried it, did not seem to have any affect on the document.

Comment: As I said, if you have Word 2010 (or 2007), it's much simpler to customize the ribbon, as Karan suggests.

Comment: None of the options mentioned above seem to exist in Office 365. :(

Comment: Customizing the ribbon to include the LTR icon worked in word 365 apps for enterprise, but did not change the position of full stops and question marks. @ZevSpitz' solution makes sure the last full stops and question marks of a paragraph are at the right hand side of the sentences, not at the extreme left of the last line of the paragraph. !

Comment: @vinnief Have you also set the text direction of the paragraph, in the paragraph formatting properties? Also, I thought Office 365 apps don't have the VBA IDE; can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Press:

- <kbd>Ctrl + Left Shift</kbd> to set the selected paragraph in Left-To-Right direction
- <kbd>Ctrl + Right Shift</kbd> to set the selected paragraph in Right-To-Left direction

Comment: For me it only changes between keyboard languages (Word 2013, though).

Answer (score 0):

in home/**styles** right click on **normal** box, choose **modify**
on the left bottom of the modify style window click on **format** and choose **paragraph**
in **indents and spacing** tab, in **general** segment choose **Left-to-right**

Comment: This changes the paragraph direction, not the direction of specific character sequences.

Comment: And Left to right is not visible in my version of Word (365 apps for enterprise, 2021)